# Pipe a stream in express (in lambda) from s3 to requester (app) fails for larger files (over a few MB)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

i'm using Express in a Lambda and trying to pipe a stream from S3 to my app. this works great when the files (pdfs mostly) are smaller than a few MBs, but when used on larger (7MB, 13MB) files (same bucket, same "folder hierarchy") instead of downloading the attached file, the app gets `{"message": "Internal server error"}`.

```
router.get(
  "/some_api",
  eaw(async function (req, res) {
    const { document } = req.params;
    const { knex } = res.locals;
    const uri = await knex("SOME_TABLE")
      .where({
        UUID: document,
      })
      .first()
      .then(({ FIELD }) => FIELD)
      .catch(() => null);
    if (!uri) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: "ResourceNotFound",
        message: `document ${document} was not found`,
      });
    }
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const { bucket, key } = AmazonS3URI(uri);

    const params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
    };

    res.attachment(key);
    try {
      const fileStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
      fileStream.pipe(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`error in s3 object streaming bucket/key ${bucket}/${key}, error: ${e}`);
      res.status(500);
      throw e;
    }
  })
);
```

I've tried changing to library s3-readable-stream, handling the headers (e.g. content-length), looked for any params for response size (found for s3 upload, this is irrelevant), and looked at ranging (but the app shouldn't handle multiple requests). Did anybody get the same problem? any solution?